# How to create a PowerPoint viewer in Android?

Tags: android, powerpoint

I am curious how to create a simple PowerPoint presentation viewer for Android. I am focusing on the Office 2003 and 2007 formats (which means .ppt and .pptx). How do I read .ppt or .pptx files and show them like a picture slideshow on my Android app?

Answer (score 4):

Well that's a loaded question.  Are you seriously thinking someone will write down the whole process for you?  Have you done any research?

I'd start by seeing if there are any java libraries for working with .ppt files.  Secondly, I'd see if I can use it in Android.  Then I'd use the Android SDK to create the app using the said library.

Easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't expecting a thorough explanation actually. I did a little research and found the Apache POI library, and wasn't quite pleased with its current version as they said it can't read a .pptx file. I will try to use it for a .ppt file though. Thanks!

Comment: @Gilang - Did you find any suitable library for ppt or pptx viewer ?